# Is it possible to issue a "VACUUM ANALYZE <tablename>" from psycopg2 or sqlalchemy for PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, vacuum

Well, the question pretty much summarises it. My db activity is very update intensive, and I want to programmatically issue a Vacuum Analyze. However I get an error that says that the query cannot be executed within a transaction. Is there some other way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL - how to run VACUUM from code outside transaction block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017463/postgresql-how-to-run-vacuum-from-code-outside-transaction-block)

Comment: Thanks, it is a duplicate. How can I mark it as one?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a flaw in the Python DB-API: it starts a transaction for you.  It shouldn't do that; whether and when to start a transaction should be up to the programmer.  Low-level, core APIs like this shouldn't babysit the developer and do things like starting transactions behind our backs.  We're big boys--we can start transactions ourself, thanks.

With psycopg2, you can disable this unfortunate behavior with an API extension: run `connection.autocommit = True`.  There's no standard API for this, unfortunately, so you have to depend on nonstandard extensions to issue commands that must be executed outside of a transaction.

No language is without its warts, and this is one of Python's.  I've been bitten by this before too.

Comment: just a comment that `connection.autocommit` is a boolean attribute, not a function.

So to execute queries outside a transaction you can set `connection.autocommit = True` before executing the VACUUM

Comment: Yeah I can't agree with this more. It's ridiculous that ever after `session.commit()` we're in a new transaction. It completely goes against how `begin; ...statements; commit;` works.

Answer (score 13):

You can turn on Postgres `autocommit` mode using SQLAlchemy's [raw_connection](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.raw_connection) (which will give you a "raw" psycopg2 connection):

```
import sqlalchemy
from psycopg2.extensions import ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT


engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url)
connection = engine.raw_connection()
connection.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("VACUUM ANALYSE table_name")
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about older versions of SQLAlchemy, but with a recent version (1.4.x or higher) you can create an autocommit session, without handling raw connections or relying on database specific hacks:

```py
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://localhost:5432')
autocommit_engine = engine.execution_options(isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT")
with Session(autocommit_engine) as session:
    session.execute(f'VACUUM ANALYZE public.my_table;')
```

The autocommit engine can be derived from any `Engine` object. The old `Engine` instance remains functional.