# sqlalchemy add index to existing sqlite3 database

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have created a database with pandas :

```
import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                          
import sqlite3                                                                                                                                                                                              
import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                                                                         
import sqlite3                                                                                                                                                                                              
import sqlalchemy                                                                                                                                                                                           
from sqlalchemy import create_engine                                                                                                                                                                        
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker                                                                                                                                                                     

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0, 1, (10, 2)), columns=['A', 'B'])                                                                                                                                      

path = 'sqlite:////home/username/Desktop/example.db'                                                                                                                                                        

engine = create_engine(path, echo=False)                                                                                                                                                                    

df.to_sql('flows', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)                                                                                                                                                 

# This is only to show I am able to read the database                                                                                                                                                                                                            
df_l = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM flows WHERE A>0 AND B<0", engine)
```

Now I would like to add one or more  indexes to the database. 
Is this case I would like to make first only the column `A` and then both the columns indices.

How can I do that?

If possible I would like a solution that uses only SqlAlchemy so that it is independent from the choice of the database.

Comment: Normally one would use a migration tool such as [alembic](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/) to handle DB migrations, but not sure how well it'd fit your use case.

Comment: My use case is very simple. Any procedure that will not require too much work (time spent learning a new tool) is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use reflection to get hold of the table that pandas created for you.

With reference to:

[SQLAlchemy Reflecting Database Objects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html)

> A Table object can be instructed to load information about itself from
>   the corresponding database schema object already existing within the
>   database. This process is called reflection. In the most simple case
>   you need only specify the table name, a MetaData object, and the
>   autoload=True flag. If the MetaData is not persistently bound, also
>   add the autoload_with argument:

you could try this:

```
meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
meta.reflect(bind=engine)
flows = meta.tables['flows']
# alternative of retrieving the table from meta:
#flows = sqlalchemy.Table('flows', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)

my_index = sqlalchemy.Index('flows_idx', flows.columns.get('A'))
my_index.create(bind=engine)

# lets confirm it is there
inspector = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(engine)
print(inspector.get_indexes('flows'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me. You will have to define the variables `psql_URI`, `table`, and `col` yourself. Here I assume that the table name / column name may be in (partial) uppercase but you want the name of the index to be lowercase.

Derived from the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72976667/3406189

```py
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

engine_psql = sqlalchemy.create_engine(psql_URI)
autocommit_engine = engine_psql.execution_options(isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT")
with Session(autocommit_engine) as session:
    session.execute(
        f'CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_{table.lower()}_{col.lower()} ON sdi_ai."{table}" ("{col}");'
    )
```