# How to do manual commit in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I'm trying to run `VACUUM` via SQLAlchemy, and it does not work, because it's in transaction block.

```
with engine.begin() as connection:
    S = orm.session.sessionmaker()()
    pd.io.sql.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s' % table_name, connection)
    df.to_sql(table_name, connection, chunksize=1000)
    S.commit()
    S.close()

engine.execute('VACUUM')
```

As you see, I do manually commit and close the session, but still there's an exception:

```
File "../__init__.py", line 115, in write_file engine.execute('VACUUM')
...
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (psycopg2.InternalError) VACUUM cannot run inside a transaction block
[SQL: 'VACUUM']
```

I tried all ways, and read through other cases and recommendations, but everyone seems to recommend `autocommit` which I can't use in this case.

How can I make `VACUUM` work here?

Comment: As far as I know pandas will create its own session with given engine, which it will commit and close after executing given command. Could it interfere with your manual commit?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931951/is-it-possible-to-issue-a-vacuum-analyze-tablename-from-psycopg2-or-sqlalche

Comment: @Primer may be. I see there are 2 connection objects, but I could not  find a commit handle in the one for pandas.

Comment: @VaoTsun The answers in that question again recommend autocommit. But I want either drop & create, or nothing. If there's a mistake in the data, I want to roll back without dropping. As I understand, with autocommit it's impossible because `drop` will be committed immediately.

Comment: `vacuum` cant be part of transaction. so you can open transaction, perform drop and commit, then set autocommit to true and do vacuum in autocommit and then set autocommit to false again - right?..