# sqlite vacuum with django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, vacuum

after insert and delete lots records into sqlite, the size of sqlite db file keeps growing, is there any way to use django vacuum the tables?

- some settings that let sqlite auto-vacuum
- or manually write own django command to vacuum

Updated:

I use [sqlite database browser](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/sqlite_database_browser_portable) to execute following SQL:

```
vacuum [my table];
commit;
```

it works great, I just want to do it program way

Comment: related (for postgresql): https://stackoverflow.com/q/1017463

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can execute raw sql as follows:

```
from django.db import connection, transaction
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Data modifying operation - commit required
cursor.execute("vacuum my_table")
transaction.commit_unless_managed()
```

though, this was kind of interesting http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html/pragma.html#pragma_auto_vacuum

maybe we can set the vacumm to be automatic, but it looks like it may worsen fragmentation.

```
cursor.execute("PRAGMA auto_vacuum=FULL")
```

http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_auto_vacuum

Comment: many thanks, although I thought some settings in django models meta-data, but the problem got solved

Comment: with Django 1.8.3 it needs ```transaction.commit()```