# Python psycopg2 not inserting into postgresql table

Tags: python, postgresql, insert, psycopg2

I'm using the following to try and insert a record into a postgresql database table, but it's not working. I don't get any errors, but there are no records in the table. Do I need a commit or something? I'm using the postgresql database that was installed with the Bitnami djangostack install.

```
import psycopg2

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='djangostack' user='bitnami' host='localhost' password='password'")
except:
    print "Cannot connect to db"

cur = conn.cursor()

try:
    cur.execute("""insert into cnet values ('r', 's', 'e', 'c', 'w', 's', 'i', 'd', 't')""")
except:
    print "Cannot insert"
```

Comment: Warning: `except:` clauses catching no specific exception are not at all helpful in debugging code.

Comment: keeping autocommit=False is preferred in many cases. 
so commit manually after executing a query: after cursor.execute(), do conn.commit()

Comment: Check out the answer in this post: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017463/postgresql-how-to-run-vacuum-from-code-outside-transaction-block)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

If don't want to have to commit each entry to the database, you can add the following line:

```
conn.autocommit = True
```

So your resulting code would be:

```
import psycopg2

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='djangostack' user='bitnami' host='localhost' password='password'")
    conn.autocommit = True
except:
    print "Cannot connect to db"

cur = conn.cursor()

try:
    cur.execute("""insert into cnet values ('r', 's', 'e', 'c', 'w', 's', 'i', 'd', 't')""")
except:
    print "Cannot insert"
```

Comment: Hi aright, do you know what happens if you don't have autocommit set to True and you never commit?  It seems that the sequence of the table increments, but where are the rows?

Comment: @DanielBaughman:  It's because sequences increment even if you don't commit; see e.g. [Sequences not affected by transactions?
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095917/sequences-not-affected-by-transactions)

Answer (score 55):

Turns out I needed `conn.commit()` at the end

Answer (score 40):

`psycopg2` is [Python DB API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)-compliant, so the auto-commit feature is off by default. You need to call [`conn.commit`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.commit) to commit any pending transaction to the database. As connections (and cursors) are context managers, you can simply use the `with` statement to automatically commit/rollback a transaction on leaving the context:

```
with conn, conn.cursor() as cur:  # start a transaction and create a cursor
    cur.execute(sql)
```

From the [docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#with-statement):

> When a connection exits the `with` block, if no exception has been
>   raised by the block, the transaction is committed. In case of
>   exception the transaction is rolled back.
>
> When a cursor exits the `with` block it is closed, releasing any
>   resource eventually associated with it. The state of the transaction
>   is not affected.

Comment: thanks -- this is the best/cleanest answer, i think.

Comment: this is great. I get my connection from a function and was able to implement this as:

            with get_connection(self.database_name, self.user_name) as conn, conn.cursor() as csr:
            csr.execute(statement)

meaning that I could reference the first value in the second value in the with statement even though the first value was not predefined.

Comment: @DonkeyKong You may need to call `conn.close()` separately after the `with` block.

Answer (score 6):

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='djangostack' user='bitnami' 
host='localhost' password='password'")
con.set_session(autocommit=True)
```

Comment: Please don't post code only answer, which will be less helpful over the period of time to understand the context. In other words - you wont get upvotes even if its the best as its hard to understand for the community.

Comment: eh, nothin wrong with just posting code. sometimes, that is a really nice and pretty way to answer questions. but yeah, i dont think that fully answered what the OP was asking for