# Why does my psycopg2 insert fail, but the subquery works?

Tags: insert, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

When I execute the following python code against my Redshift database the insert fails, even though the subquery operates correctly.  I'm pretty sure this is some simple concept I'm missing here, but I don't know what it is.  Any suggestions on how to make this work?

```
con_f = psycopg2.connect(dbname=dbname, host=host, port=port, user=user, password=password)
cur_f = con_f.cursor()

move_qry = 'insert into schema.' + target_table + ' (SELECT * from ' + staging_tbl +  ');'
print(move_qry)
cur_f.execute(move_qry)
print(cur_f.query)
print(cur_f.statusmessage)

insert into schema.tbl_final (SELECT * from staging.tbl_final_tmp);
insert into schema.tbl_final (SELECT * from staging.tbl_final_tmp);
INSERT 0 6388714
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the insert fails"?

Comment: Nothing gets written to schema.tbl_final

Comment: If you run `SELECT * from staging.tbl_final_tmp` before the INSERT, does it show anything? What happens if you run the same commands from an SQL client instead of Python?

Comment: When running the same commands in SQL client dBeaver, the insert succeeds

Comment: Does this fix your issue? [Python psycopg2 not inserting into postgresql table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18068901/174777)